# My program is printing the wrong thing after completing, and I can't figure out why. C++

Tags: c++

When the program is operating correctly, it is supposed to ask the user for a code (A, C ,D) and then ask for a Radius.

Which it does fine.

But when it's finished it is supposed to cout something that looks like "The area of a circle with radius 6.75 is 143.14"

But when I run mine, it prints "The area of a circle with radius 6.75 is A." I just can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong, and any help is greatly appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

/*run this program using the console pauser or add your own     getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
char Code;
double Radius;

//promt for a code and A, C, or D
cout << "Please enter your code A, C, or D ";

// read the input
cin >> Code;

//promt user for value of radius
cout << "Please enter a value for the radius";

//read the input radius
cin >> Radius;
// based on the code, calculate the required computed result
double Const;

Const = 3.1416;

'A' == Const * Radius;

'C' == 2 * Const * Radius;  

'D' == 2 * Radius;  

if (Code == 'A')
    cout << "The area of a circle with radius" << Radius <<   "is" << 'A' << endl;


else if (Code == 'C')
    cout << "The circumference of a circle with radius" <<  Radius << "is" << 'C' << endl;


else if (Code == 'D')
    cout << "The diameter of a circle with radius" << Radius << "is" << 'D' << endl;    
//output the result

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variables do not go in single quotes, and `==` does not assign.

Comment: And programs (nearly) never print the wrong thing. They just do what you tell them!

Comment: There should have been a "warning: statement has no effect" for `'A' == Const * Radius;` or your compiler's equivalent message. If you aren't getting these warnings, check your development environment documentation for how to turn them on and read them. Your bacon they can save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better review the latest lesson in C++ first.

Here is the fix for your code:

```
double a = Const * Radius; //'A' == Const * Radius;

double c = 2 * Const * Radius; //'C' == 2 * Const * Radius;  

double d = 2 * Radius; //'D' == 2 * Radius;  

if (Code == 'A')
    cout << "The area of a circle with radius" << Radius <<   "is" << a /*'A'*/<< endl;


else if (Code == 'C')
    cout << "The circumference of a circle with radius" <<  Radius << "is" << c /*'C'*/ << endl;


else if (Code == 'D')
    cout << "The diameter of a circle with radius" << Radius << "is" << d /*'D'*/ << 

endl;
```

'A', 'B', 'C' are values as well as 1, 3, 100, etc.

`=` is an assignment operator while `==` is compare operator.

Once you write something like `'A' == Radius;` it will be evaluated to boolean (most likely `false` value) and that's it. In the same way you can write `false;` or `5;` in your code. It does nothing at all.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex. I'm still relatively new to c++, like I've only been in the class for 2 weeks, and you've helped me immensely!

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the value but making it equal to that. by the you can assign a value to char.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

/*run this program using the console pauser or add your own     getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
char Code;
double Radius;

//promt for a code and A, C, or D
cout << "Please enter your code A, C, or D ";

// read the input
cin >> Code;

//promt user for value of radius
cout << "Please enter a value for the radius";

//read the input radius
cin >> Radius;
// based on the code, calculate the required computed result
double Const;

Const = 3.1416;
/*      NO need of this. you can't assign value to a char.
'A' == Const * Radius;
you have used == sign whic is not assigning
'C' = 2 * Const * Radius;  

'D' = 2 * Radius;  
*/
if (Code == 'A'){
    float temp;    //change
    temp=Const * Radius;   //change
    cout << "The area of a circle with radius" << Radius <<   "is" << temp << endl;

}


else if (Code == 'C'){
    float temp;
    temp=2 * Const * Radius; 
    cout << "The circumference of a circle with radius" <<  Radius << "is" << temp<< endl; 
}



else if (Code == 'D'){
    float temp;
    temp=2 * Radius;  
    cout << "The diameter of a circle with radius" << Radius << "is" << temp << endl;    
}
    //Hope this helps.
//output the result

return 0;
}
```